# Find out default SQL Server schema for session

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a requirement to know what the current default schema is in a SQL script that is doing some DDL. I don't need to set the schema, but I do need to get a reference to it (name or ID) into a variable. The script may be running as a windows login, so the following isn't sufficient:

```
SELECT name, default_schema_name 
FROM sys.database_principals 
WHERE type = 'S' and name = SYSTEM_USER --SYSTEM User won't be named as a principal
```

I've thought of doing it by creating a randomly named object in the current schema, and then looking at its details in the information_schema, but does anyone have a tidier way?

I'm working in SQL Server 2005.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

How about this.

`SELECT SCHEMA_NAME()`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175068.aspx

> SCHEMA_NAME will return the name of the default schema of the caller

Alternatively `SCHEMA_ID()`

Answer (score 6):

How about using `DATABASE_PRINCIPAL_ID` to get the db principal of the current user?

```
SELECT name, default_schema_name 
FROM sys.database_principals 
WHERE type = 'S' and name = USER_NAME(DATABASE_PRINCIPAL_ID())
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's what you can do to see more information about your current schema:

```
select sc.name as schemaname, sp.[name] as owner,
sp.default_database_name as [database]  from sys.schemas  sc
inner join sys.server_principals sp on sc.principal_id =  sp.principal_id

select sc.name as schemaname, sp.[name] as owner,
sp.default_database_name as [database],sp.*  from sys.schemas  sc
inner join sys.server_principals sp on sc.principal_id =  sp.principal_id

SELECT name, default_schema_name  
FROM sys.database_principals WHERE type = 'S'
```

I hope this helps.