# How to have SQL Server function user_name return dbo

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have a user (`testQA`) created in a SQL Server database and the user is the database owner but when I try to run the `user_name` command, I get the actual username rather than `dbo`. I want to run some upgrade scripts provide by 3rd party where in there are statements like below

```
if exists (select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where TABLE_NAME = 'TAb1' and  TABLE_SCHEMA = user_name() )
    drop table TAb1
```

For this to run correct the user_name needs to be `dbo` but somehow the user which I created always return `testQA` when I run the `user_name`. Can I make any changes so it returns `dbo`?

Comment: You should NOT be using INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES to determine the schema of an object. That data is not always up to date and there for backwards compatibility. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186224.aspx.

Comment: schema and users are two different things. if you want create a new schema under the database which is the same as your username.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing username and schema name. Username is the name of your user (here TestQA). Schema name is the name of the schema your user, or table, or any DB object depends on (here dbo, aka ".").

In order to get the active user's default schema, use `SELECT SCHEMA_NAME()`

More info: [Find out default SQL Server schema for session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5513053/find-out-default-sql-server-schema-for-session)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the 3rd party script is assuming that you have tables created against a schema that matches your user name, perhaps to stop it being run blind and damaging tables.

To make it execute using 'dbo' instead of the logged in username just go:

`if exists (select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where TABLE_NAME = 'TAb1' and  TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' )
drop table TAb1`